# In The Sound of Music, which car part did the nun steal?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sound-of-music

By the end of The Sound of Music, when the Nazi soldiers leave the abbey, their cars will not start, because nuns stole some engine parts.

What is the engine part they stole?

Comment: I thought it looked like spark plug wires, but I haven't seen it in a while, and I am not even sure if those vehicles would have spark plugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distributor cap.

It was a commonplace trick at the time to disable a vehicle by removing the rotor arm from the distributor, but this small part would be harder to show on film.

The distributor cap is simple to unclip and remove - taking just seconds.  It is also a clearly recognisable part.

Comment: If you could provide a screen shot I'd surely give you an up-vote. Your answer makes good sense to me, and feels very logical. Unfortunately I'm not willing to watch the movie to confirm your answer.